# How to take N bits from a ByteString?

Tags: haskell, binary, binary-data

I know how to split a List into 2 parts -- `(a1, rest) = splitAt N myList`. But with `ByteString` it won't work because  we operate with bits, not bytes.

How can I take N bits from `ByteString` ? Or split it into 2 parts, the 1st part should be of N bits of the size.

Comment: [splitAt](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:splitAt)?

Comment: `ByteString` are 8-bit arrays, so if you want to take 16 bits `splitAt 2` should work. If the amount of bits is not divisible by 8 I don't think you can achive it, but I am not so sure.

Comment: @MarkSeemann my question says - "bits". `splitAt` operates on bytes

Comment: @lsmor why my question says if not that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can't take bits from a `ByteString`. You can, however, take bits from a `BitString`, using the `bitstring` library.

```
import qualified Data.BitString as BitS


myBits = BitS.bitString myList

(a1, rest) = BitS.splitAt n myBits
```

Answer (score 0):

`Data.Bits` provides bitwise operations: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html
you can first split the bytestring into 2 bytestrings with `splitAt` and a word8 and then read the word8 bit by bit with `testBit` and `shiftL`/`shiftR`

```
type Frag = ([Bool], ByteString, [Bool])  -- naive representation of a list of bits

splitBS :: Int -> ByteString -> (Frag, Frag)
splitBS bits bs =
  let (byte, remb) = bits `quotRem` 8
      (bs1, t） = splitAt byte bs 
      w = head t
      bs2 = tail t
      (b1, b2) = splitWord remb w
   in (([], bs1, b1), (b2, bs2, []))

fromBits :: Bits a => a -> [Bool]
fromBits b
    | b == zeroBits = []
    | otherwise     = testBit b 0 : fromBits (shiftR b 1)

fromBits' :: Bits a => a -> [Bool]
fromBits' = reverse . fromBits

splitWord :: Int -> Word -> ([Bool], [Bool])
splitWord n w =
  let bl = fromBits' w
   in (take n bl, drop n bl)
```

Comment: yes, it does. how exactly to use in a real example?

Comment: are all these 4 functions needed to simply take N bits from a ByteString? How do I use that? what's Frag, why is it needed?

Answer (score 0):

Below, a full example. Given an `n` and a `ByteString` it'll return a `[Bool]` representing bits. Recall that is much more efficient to use bitwise functions provided by `Data.Bits`

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Bits as Bits

example :: B.ByteString
example = "abc"

takeNBits :: Int -> B.ByteString -> [Bool]
takeNBits n bs = take n $ B.foldl' toBool [] bs
  where toBool l w = (Bits.testBit w <$> [0..(Bits.finiteBitSize w)]) ++ l

main = print $ takeNBits 18 example
```